# Push notification server implementation

Tags: push-notification, message-queue, mqtt

I have a mobile and web application where I would like to send my users push notifications. I'm planning to use a message broker which supports MQTT protocol for push notification server implementation. User base is expected to reach 1 million and many notifications are user specific. My question is do I have to use separate queue for each user or is there any other-way to sort this out without creating a queue for each user?

Answer (score 1):

MQTT doesn't use queues, it uses topics

And if you only want a single user to receive a message then yes they will need an individual topic each.

Comment: Thank you. I want to clarify that If I create individual topics for each users (in millions) by assigning unique id's or any primary-key values can an MQTT server handle that amount of topics?.

Comment: You will always have to test a system at the scale you're talking about, you will need to build a cluster to handle that many concurrent users, but topics are transient, they only really exist at the moment a message is published

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that out.!